# Passing data to PHP via Ajax without using a submit button

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've had a look around and unfortunately the solutions I've found on the site don't appear to address my issue below.

Basically I'm doing a project where I need to effectively set up a diary - the user writes in a textarea element and this is passed via PHP to a database and stored for the user. In the lecturer's video, it appears he's doing without using a submit button (even if he's not, I think it'd be an interesting thing to learn how to do).

I'm having some issues though. Here's my PHP:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if(array_key_exists("id", $_COOKIE)) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $_COOKIE['id'];

    }

    if(array_key_exists("id",$_SESSION)) {

        echo "Logged in: <p><a href='secretDiaryFinal2.php?logout=1'>
        Log out</a></p>";

    } else {

        header("Location: secretDiaryFinal2.php");

    }


/*    I'm putting in the database update later, for now I just wanted to check if I could 
actually create the POST variable below*/

    $msg = "";

    if(array_key_exists('diaryEntry',$_POST)) {

        $msg = $_POST['diaryEntry'];


    } else  {

        $msg = "Some kind of PHP error";

    }



?>
```

The relevant HTML:

```
  <body>

    <div id="testDiv">

        <? echo $msg ?>

    </div>

    <div class="container" id="diaryArea">

    <form method="post">
        <textarea id="diary" value=""></textarea>
    </form>

    </div>
```

The relevant JQuery (I'm very weak on Ajax and I suspect there's a lot of issues here - also note the url I'm using is actually in the same script as the JQuery, I'm not certain if that works?) is below.

The basic idea is that every time the user types, the database should be updated (I realise this is a lot of calls to the server, I'll probably replace it with a timed command):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#diary").keyup(function () {

              var dataString = $("#diary").val();

              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "loggedInPageFinal.php",
                data: ({diaryEntry:dataString}),
                success: function(data) {

                    console.log(data);

                }


              });

              return false;

        });




    </script>
```

Many thanks in advance and apologies for my poor code!

Answer (score 0):

```
var DataString = $("#diary").val();
$.post( "loggedInPageFinal.php",{dataString:DataString }, function( data ) {
   console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax script actually does work.
But your php code isn't returning anything. put `exit($msg);` at the end of the code and see what happens.